# Can a method know the type of Object that is calling it (i.e. the subtype that is calling it)

Tags: java

This relates to the Java language.

Let's say I have we have a super class A and subclasses X and Y. I have a method in A that needs to know the type of X and Y (it's an external library).

I have a method on A called `someMethod()`. My question is: in the `someMethod()` implementation is there a way to find out whether it is being called by X or Y?

Please let me know if this is not clear.

EDIT^2:

The concrete situation in class A looks like this.

```
public void delete() {
    Datastore ds = Dao.instance().getDatabase();
    ds.delete(this.getClass(),this.id);
}
```

and I'd like to be able to do X.delete() and Y.delete()

Comment: Why would you need to know the type? If the behavior is different, then write different implementations of ``someMethod()`` in ``X`` and ``Y``.

Comment: I am using the Morphia library with Mongodb. It needs to know the type of the class so it can get the proper data. However ideally I'd like to have a superclass called Model that has a method called read() so that I can then call MyObject.read() and it gets read. But I have done what you suggest.

Comment: No, and it shouldn't. This is called 'state orientation' and it is considered extremely bad design practice. If you want the method to do something different, pass another parameter, or write another method.

Comment: @EJP ... it seems that it is using the class name as a parameter, (I am not sure if that makes sense) to figure out which Collection to get the data from (again I don't know enough to know if I understand correctly).

Comment: @Ankur There are no parameters in the code you posted. You didn't post any code. I can't see what you're talking about.

Comment: @EJP (Added some info to the question) To me it seems the value of `this.getClass()` is being used as a parameter in the Datastore.delete() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily find out whether the method is called *on* an X or Y, using [`getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29):

```
public void someMethod() {
    System.out.println(getClass()); // Will display the execution-time type
}
```

But of course that public method could be called *by* any class (not just X or Y). If you need to get *that* information, you'll need to get the stack trace - which may not always be reliable due to inlining etc. The right course of action will depend on *why* you want this information.

Comment: Thanks Jon. My decision is between doing "something dangerous" and rewriting CRUD methods for 12 different objects. Since I'm the only one using this code (and it's a personal project) I'll go with reducing the code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Yes: simply call [`getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29). For example:

```
class A {
  public void someMethod() {
    System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName());
  }
}
```

This would print out either `X` or `Y` depending on the runtime class of the object on which it is invoked.